# How can I change the duration of a front-end session in a component?

Tags: user, session

I have made a component where it is tedious when the session ends after 15 or 30 minutes and you have to log in again. For all other pages, however, this time is fine.

Is there a way to temporarily change this duration as soon as you get to this page or call up this component in the frontend area?

I've already googled it, but haven't found any good results. I know that you can also adjust this value in general. However, this is not the solution in my case.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On HTML pages you can use Keepalive script which periodically makes AJAX requests to prevent session expiration. It's widely used across the CMS on form pages. Usage in view layout:

```
$this->document->getWebAssetManager()->useScript('keepalive');
```